# React Native Sortable FlastList zIndex

Tags: javascript, react-native

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to add drag/drop to sort functionality to the FlatList in `iOS`. I'm fully aware there are packages out there that solve this problem, but as mentioned above. I'm building from scratch to learn.

I am mostly there, however - the problem I've run into is to do with `zIndex`. My `PanResponder` activates, and the list item becomes draggable however no matter how high I set the `zIndex` of the element the stacking order remains the same.

I tried creating a ghost view that sits outside the FlatList and then passing the `dy` of the dragged list item to it via `state` and `props` which works, but performance is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

There are two WIP on github, maybe it can be uselfull for you ?

https://github.com/nerdmed/react-native-sortable-flatlist
and
https://github.com/vTrip/FlatListSortable

maybe it can be usefull if you can share your code too.